# If/elsif/else statement is skipping straight to else

Tags: ruby, arrays, if-statement

I have the below if statement, but no matter what input I give to matrix (which is an array, and no I can't change the name) the console only outputs "Next turn!". The console will quite happily display that matrix[0], matrix[1] and matrix[2] are all "0" but then continue straight to the else statement. Is there anything wrong with the statement?

```
def checkwinner
            if @matrix[0] == "0" && @matrix[1] == "0" && @matrix[2] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[3] == "0" && @matrix[4] == "0" && @matrix[5] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[6] == "0" && @matrix[7] == "0" && @matrix[8] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[0] == "0" && @matrix[3] == "0" && @matrix[6] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[1] == "0" && @matrix[4] == "0" && @matrix[7] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit    
            elsif @matrix[2] == "0" && @matrix[5] == "0" && @matrix[8] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[0] == "0" && @matrix[4] == "0" && @matrix[8] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[2] == "0" && @matrix[4] == "0" && @matrix[6] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[0] == "1" && @matrix[1] == "1" && @matrix[2] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[3] == "1" && @matrix[4] == "1" && @matrix[5] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[6] == "1" && @matrix[7] == "1" && @matrix[8] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[0] == "1" && @matrix[3] == "1" && @matrix[6] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[1] == "1" && @matrix[4] == "1" && @matrix[7] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit    
            elsif @matrix[2] == "1" && @matrix[5] == "1" && @matrix[8] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[0] == "1" && @matrix[4] == "1" && @matrix[8] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[2] == "1" && @matrix[4] == "1" && @matrix[6] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            else puts "Next turn!"      
            end
        end
```

Whole code file below:

```
# Ruby code file - All your code should be located between the comments provided.

# Add any additional gems and global variables here
# require 'sinatra'     # remove '#' character to run sinatra wen server

# Main class module
module OXs_Game
# Input and output constants processed by subprocesses. MUST NOT change.
NOUGHT = 0
CROSS = 1

class Game
    attr_reader :matrix, :input, :output, :player1, :player2, :winner
    attr_writer :matrix, :input, :output, :player1, :player2, :winner

    def initialize(input, output)
        @input = input
        @output = output
    end

    # Any code/methods aimed at passing the RSpect tests should be added below.
        def start
            @output.puts "Welcome to Noughts and Crosses!"
            @output.puts "Starting game..."
            @output.puts "Created by:Stephen Mitchell"
            @output.puts "Player 1: 0 and Player 2: 1"
        end

        def created_by
            return "Stephen Mitchell"
        end

        def student_id
            return 51441219
        end

        def setplayer1
            @player1 = 0
        end

        def setplayer2
            @player2 = 1
        end

        def clearmatrix
            @matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
        end

        def getmatrixvalue(n)
            @matrix[n]
        end

        def setmatrixvalue(i, v)
            @i = 1
            @v = "0"
            @matrix[i] = "0"            
        end

        def displaykey(matrix)
            @matrix = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
            @output.puts "Table key:\n|#{matrix[0]}|#{matrix[1]}|#{matrix[2]}|\n|#{matrix[3]}|#{matrix[4]}|#{matrix[5]}|\n|#{matrix[6]}|#{matrix[7]}|#{matrix[8]}|\n"
        end

        def displaymatrix
            @matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
            @output.puts "Table status:\n|#{matrix[0]}|#{matrix[1]}|#{matrix[2]}|\n|#{matrix[3]}|#{matrix[4]}|#{matrix[5]}|\n|#{matrix[6]}|#{matrix[7]}|#{matrix[8]}|\n"
        end

        def finish
            @output.puts "Finishing game..."
        end

        def displaymenu
            @output.puts "Menu: (1)Start | (2)New | (9)Exit\n"
        end

        def checkwinner
            if @matrix[0] == "0" && @matrix[1] == "0" && @matrix[2] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[3] == "0" && @matrix[4] == "0" && @matrix[5] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[6] == "0" && @matrix[7] == "0" && @matrix[8] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[0] == "0" && @matrix[3] == "0" && @matrix[6] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[1] == "0" && @matrix[4] == "0" && @matrix[7] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit    
            elsif @matrix[2] == "0" && @matrix[5] == "0" && @matrix[8] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[0] == "0" && @matrix[4] == "0" && @matrix[8] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[2] == "0" && @matrix[4] == "0" && @matrix[6] == "0" then
                puts "Player 1 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[0] == "1" && @matrix[1] == "1" && @matrix[2] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[3] == "1" && @matrix[4] == "1" && @matrix[5] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[6] == "1" && @matrix[7] == "1" && @matrix[8] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[0] == "1" && @matrix[3] == "1" && @matrix[6] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[1] == "1" && @matrix[4] == "1" && @matrix[7] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit    
            elsif @matrix[2] == "1" && @matrix[5] == "1" && @matrix[8] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[0] == "1" && @matrix[4] == "1" && @matrix[8] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            elsif @matrix[2] == "1" && @matrix[4] == "1" && @matrix[6] == "1" then
                puts "Player 2 wins!"
                finish
                exit
            else puts "Next turn!"      
            end
        end


    # Any code/methods aimed at passing the RSpect tests should be added above.



end
end
```

Main program

```
# Main program
module OXs_Game
@input = STDIN
@output = STDOUT
g = Game.new(@input, @output)
matrixkey = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
playing = true
input = ""
option = 0
turn = 0

# Any code added to output the activity messages to the command line window should be added below.

g.start
g.displaykey(matrixkey)
g.displaymatrix
puts "Please select one of the following:"
g.displaymenu
menu_input = gets.chomp.to_s


while matrix.include? ("_") do
    puts "Table status:\n|#{matrix[0]}|#{matrix[1]}|#{matrix[2]}|\n|#{matrix[3]}|#{matrix[4]}|#{matrix[5]}|\n|#{matrix[6]}|#{matrix[7]}|#{matrix[8]}|\n"
    g.checkwinner
    turn += 1
    puts "player1 turn"
    x = gets.chomp.to_s
    case x
        when "1"
            matrix[0] = "0"
        when "2"
            matrix[1] = "0"
        when "3"
            matrix[2] = "0"
        when "4"
            matrix[3] = "0"
        when "5"
            matrix[4] = "0" 
        when "6"
            matrix[5] = "0"
        when "7"
            matrix[6] = "0" 
        when "8"
            matrix[7] = "0" 
        when "9"
            matrix[8] = "0" 
    end 
    puts "Table status:\n|#{matrix[0]}|#{matrix[1]}|#{matrix[2]}|\n|#{matrix[3]}|#{matrix[4]}|#{matrix[5]}|\n|#{matrix[6]}|#{matrix[7]}|#{matrix[8]}|\n"
    g.checkwinner
    turn +=1
    puts "player2 turn"
    y = gets.chomp.to_s
    case y
        when "1"
            matrix[0] = "1"
        when "2"
            matrix[1] = "1"
        when "3"
            matrix[2] = "1"
        when "4"
            matrix[3] = "1"
        when "5"
            matrix[4] = "1" 
        when "6"
            matrix[5] = "1"
        when "7"
            matrix[6] = "1" 
        when "8"
            matrix[7] = "1" 
        when "9"
            matrix[8] = "1" 
    end 
end

# Any code added to output the activity messages to the command line window should be added above.

end
```

Comment: could it be that the matrix values are numbers (`1, 2, 3`) and not strings (`"1", "2", "3"`)?

Comment: You mean the numbers in the square brackets [0]? Those aren't the values, they're array index and shouldn't be strings as far as I'm aware.

Comment: No, I meant the _actual matrix values_ - `0 != "0"`

Comment: Based on this code alone there's no way to tell what the problem might be other than that the array doesn't contain what you think it contains. Please show a complete example that we can run and see the problem ourselves.

Comment: Alright, I'll post the whole thing, hold on.

Comment: Needs a lot of clean-up, like `matrix[x.to_i] = "1"` is a lot easier than breaking out stuff with a case statement. You should work to try and cut down on the rampant repetition in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying a local version of `matrix` in your gameloop (the `while matrix.include?` loop).

`checkwinner`, however, is called on the `Game` instance `g`. `Game#checkwinner` is examining an instance variable `@matrix`, which is *not* the same `matrix` you manipulate in your game loop.

You do not modify the matrix you check, hence `checkwinner` will always be looking at the same data.

There is a very confusing mix of local and instance variables here, which indicates a significant misunderstanding of either what you're doing, or how you're supposed to be doing it.

The turns (players' moves) should be manipulating the `Game`'s `@matrix` instance variable.

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while to understand your answer, but that really helped. Significant misunderstanding may be understating it a bit...

Comment: @hoopa It's a process :) Nothing's obvious until it is.

Comment: Absolutely, it makes so much sense now that you've pointed it out to me!

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to your question, but a tip how to improve your coding style.

You have a lot of repetition in your code and your code will benefit if you try to avoid that. For example your ``checkwinner` method can be simplified to something like this:

```
PATTERNS = [
  [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9],  # rows
  [1,4,6], [2,5,8], [3,6,9],  # columns
  [1,5,9], [3,5,7]            # diagonal
]

def checkwinner
  PATTERNS.each do |pattern|
    values = pattern.map { |position| @matrix[position] }.uniq

    winner = 1 if values == ['0']
    winner = 2 if values == ['1']

    if winner
      puts "Player #{winner} wins!"
      finish
      exit
    end
  end

  puts "Next turn!"
end
```

Or instead of the long `case` blocks in your `while` loop, think about something like this:

```
if ('1'..'9').include?(x)
  matrix[x.to_i - 1] = '0'
end

...

if ('1'..'9').include?(y)
  matrix[y.to_i - 1] = '1'
end
```